# PHP Page show user status with refresh

Tags: php, ajax, refresh, status

I have a PHP-Script thats queries User-Status via SOAP.
I want to refresh the Page when the status for a user changes, for example when the user makes a call or hangs up.
How can I refresh the Page fast and smooth to always show the latest user status?

I read about Ajax and searched for a solution in HTML5. What is your advise?

Thanks for any helpful post :-)

Comment: And what did you read about `AJAX`? It worth your spent time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to not load and interpret soap before page load.

Make two pages.

1 content page that displays everything you want, without the "latest status"
When the content page is loaded, make an ajax request to the 2nd page.(jQuery example)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax("lateststatus.php").done(function(data){
      // Change the name of the element to the element where you want to display the data
      document.getElementById("mycontentdiv").innerHTML = data;
      });
});
```

Then in the 2nd php file(lateststatus.php) load the soap file, interpret and generate only the html code you want to display in the content div.

That's it in a nutshell.